# Как в JS создать массив элементов, у каждого из которых будут свойства?

Tags: javascript

Пробовал так:

```
var section = [
  link: [],
  filename: [],
  name: [],
  author: [],
  material: [],
  scale: [],
  date: [],
  museum: [],
  city: [],
  notation: [],
];
```

Но это ведь неправильно?

Заполнять же думал так:

```
section[i].link.push(link);
section[i].filename.push(filename);
section[i].name.push(name);
section[i].author.push(author);
section[i].material.push(material);
section[i].scale.push(scale);
section[i].date.push(date);
section[i].museum.push(museum);
section[i].city.push(city);
section[i].notation.push(notation);
```

В чем и где ошибки, если они есть?

Comment: синтаксическая ошибка: 
`VM9690:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var section = [];

section.push({
  link: link,
  filename: filename,
  name: name,
  author: author,
  material: material,
  scale: scale,
  date: date,
  museum: museum,
  city: city,
  notation: notation
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Section = function() {return {
    link: [],
    filename: [],
    name: [],
    author: [],
    material: [],
    scale: [],
    date: [],
    museum: [],
    city: [],
    notation: [],
}};
```

Это даст вам создавать новые секции:

```
section[i] = new Section();
section[i].city.push(someCity);
```

И так далее.

Расширять массив своими свойствами несколько неправильно, да. Хотя семантически верно.

Отличие от предыдущего ответа в том, что здесь создание новой секции сосредоточено в одном месте, не придётся копировать массив свойств.

Comment: нет смысла в `new`

Comment: Поясните, почему нет смысла в использовании new? Вы о том, что, если просто дёрнуть метод, не как конструктор, вернётся тоже самое? Да, вернётся. Но вариант с использованием чуть проще расширять.

Comment: чем проще расширять?

Comment: @Grundy, ок, стоило не полениться и писать this.link = ... и так далее. Проще расширять -- тем, что можно будет инкапсулировать логику работы с этими объектами внутри этих объектов.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
var section = {
  link: [],
  filename: [],
  name: [],
  author: [],
  material: [],
  scale: [],
  date: [],
  museum: [],
  city: [],
  notation: [],
};
```

это создание объекта с свойствами массивами. Обращение к элементам будет так

```
section.link.push(...)
```

если вам нужен массив объектов со свойствами, тогда так

```
var section = [];
section.push({
  link: [],
  filename: [],
  name: [],
  author: [],
  material: [],
  scale: [],
  date: [],
  museum: [],
  city: [],
  notation: [],
});
```

Comment: Нет, так у меня было. Как в таком случае заносить туда элементы?